# Brackets debug menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, adobe-brackets

I've been developing a Node app with Brackets. In the Debug menu of Brackets there are three options that I can't make them work: 'Enable Node Debugger', 'Log Node State to Console' and 'Restart Node'.

[image]

I start my app in a terminal with 'npm start' or 'node app.js' and nothing! How can I make them work?

Comment: Try install and use `theseus`: https://github.com/adobe-research/theseus#install

Comment: Yes, I'm using theseus already. But the options still don't work. Maybe these options are for debugging brackets?